# javax.imageio.ImageIo.write behavior

Tags: java, png, javax.imageio

I need to convert some java BufferedImage to png (as byte array).

I am using the well known method *write(RenderedImage im,String formatName, OutputStream output)* which is static and it seems to work well:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
  baos.flush();
  byte[] dataToReturn = baos.toByteArray();
```

But, in case of multithreading process the *write* method seems to hang (synchronous behavior ?) and the cpu load is increasing during the processing of lets say 50 images at the same time (may be not related).

My questions are:

1. Is the *write* method really ThreadSafe ? It seems to be but it also seems syncrhonous and so it can takes some times to process several BufferedImage at the same time.
2. Is there any other way to convert a BufferedImage to a png in Java (library or legacy)?
3. What is the best method toward performance ?

Thanks

Comment: `50 images at the same time` how many parallel threads your system is able to process? Why not creating a queue which process them in background? What size `bufferedImage` have in average?

Comment: 50 images was only while benchmarking the process, it will be more or less 5 to 10 image that has to be processed using 2 or 3 threads (one after another). The average size can be more thant 700 Ko.

Comment: 1: Yes, it is (whether or not it internally synchronizes on some resource has nothing to do with thread *safety*). 2. Yes (Google is your friend here). 3. Measure (using a profiler) the various solutions you found in step 2. Actually, using a profiler is a great way to see if you run into a bottleneck due to synchronization in step 1 as well.